# Return next cell value from a range based on selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple worksheets and each sheet contains skill details.

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqEfs.png)

```
Skills                       Name
Programs(C#, VB, Python)     C#
OS(Windows, Linux)      
DB(Oracle, SQL)              Oracle
```

My requirement is, if user put skills as "Programs(C#, VB, Python)", then return next cell value i.e. "C#"

My code.

```
Private Sub BtnReport_Click()
Dim SkillName As String
Dim SkillRng As Range
Dim rng As Range
'Dim nextblankrow As Long
'Dim lastrow As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim val As String

SkillName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Admin").Range("L4")

If SkillName = "" Then
    MsgBox "Select a skill name"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Sheets(2).Select
'Set rng = Sheets(2).Range("B14:B100").Find(What:=SkillName)
'MsgBox rng.Value

Sheets("Report").Select
Sheets("Report").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("Report").Cells(1, 1) = "Skill Name"
Sheets("Report").Cells(1, 2) = "Resource"

'''''For i = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
'''''    Set rng = Sheets(i).Range("B14:C100")
'''''    Set SkillRng = rng.Find(What:=SkillName)
'''''    If Not SkillRng Is Nothing Then
'''''        Sheets("Report").Cells(i + 1, 1) = SkillRng.Value
'''''        MsgBox rng.Cells.Value
''''''        Sheets("Report").Cells(i + 1, 2) = rng.Offset(RowoffSet = 1, Columnoffset = 2).Value
''''''        Sheets("Report").Cells(i + 1, 2) = SkillRng.Cells(Selection.Row, Selection.Column + 1).Value
'''''        Sheets("Report").Cells(i + 1, 3) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).name
'''''    End If
'''''Next i
    Set rng = Sheets(2).Range("B14:C100")
    Set SkillRng = rng.Find(What:=SkillName)

    For x = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For y = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            If rng.Cells(x, y) = SkillRng Then
'                Sheets("Report").Cells(2, 2) = rng.Cells(x, y + 1)
                MsgBox SkillRng
                MsgBox x
                MsgBox y
                val = Cells(x, y).Value
 '               val = SkillRng
                MsgBox val
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
```

Comment: There is no screenshot in your post. Also, the code given is inadequate to understand completely. Can you post the full code?

Comment: Sorry Naresh for the confusion, I have edited and reposted again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will give you everything with little editing for sheet numbers and intended Report cell values

There is difference between sheets and worksheets. Sheets also include charts. So for your purpose use worksheets. Also, you have to skip the Report and Admin Worksheets for evaluation in the loop. If your report and Admin worksheets are (1) and (2) then start loop from 3. If you loop also evaluates these sheets and if it finds skillname in range to find (rng) in these sheets values from these sheets will also appear in your report.

```
Private Sub BtnReport_Click()
Dim SkillName As String
Dim SkillRng As Range
Dim rng As Range

SkillName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Admin").Range("L4")

If SkillName = "" Then
MsgBox "Select a skill name"
Exit Sub
End If

Sheets("Report").Select
Sheets("Report").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("Report").Cells(1, 1) = "Skill Name"
Sheets("Report").Cells(1, 2) = "Resource"

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
Set rng = Worksheets(i).Range("B14:C100")
Set SkillRng = rng.Find(What:=SkillName)
k = Sheets("Report").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
If Not SkillRng Is Nothing Then
Sheets("Report").Cells(k, 1) = SkillName
Sheets("Report").Cells(k, 2) = SkillRng.Value
Sheets("Report").Cells(k, 3) = SkillRng.offset(0,1)
Sheets("Report").Cells(k, 4) = Worksheets(i).name
End If
Next i

End sub
```

Comment: Thanks Naresh, however the report is in any position, hence I have included the "If Not SkillRng". But how to get value of names against the Skills as per the sample data given?

Comment: In your question you wanted name of the sheet (Resource) for the skiiname?

Comment: No, Resource is the column name of the Report sheet

Comment: Does this answer your question?